# Bootstrap layout for small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to implement Bootstrap correctly in my proyect, but im getting stuck. What i want to do is to have different layouts for my app in case it is accessed by a small device.

I created a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/a4v4qk6uW0eDcMCfoPkC?p=info) to make it easier. What i want to do is to place the Red div between the grey and orange one.

**EDIT** I tried to create a row with the business-header and the login div and i can see the result i want for small devices but not for large ones.

Here you have two images, the first one is how i want it to look like in large devices and the second one is for smalls.

Large device layout:

[image]

Small device layout:

[image]

```
<header class="business-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                    <h1><a class="tagline hipervinculo green" ui-sref="home" translate>titulo.alergenos</a></h1>
                </div>

                <div class="login col-lg-3 col-sm-3" ng-controller="LoginController">
                    <div class="panelLogin">
                          <label for="usuario" translate>input.usuario</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" ng-model="loginUsuario">
                          <label for="contrasena" translate>input.contrasena</label>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="contrasena" ng-model="loginPassword">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="login()" translate>input.autenticar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>


<div class="container orange">
            <legend translate>Welcome</legend>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="descripcion in texto">{{descripcion}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2 translate>home.titulo.queHacemos</h2>
                <p translate>home.descripcion.queHacemos</p>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#">Call to Action &raquo;</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
</div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: While we don't expect top-of-the-line grammar, correct spelling will only help you get attention.

Comment: Well... Excuse me for my english, im trying my best. I edited the question, maybe its better now?

Comment: Have a friend help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/8JqYaMNqZslF6CFRBqsX?p=info)

Here's the relevant bit:

```
            <div class="login col-lg-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs" ng-controller="LoginController">
                <div class="panelLogin">
                      <label for="usuario" translate>input.usuario</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" ng-model="loginUsuario">
                      <label for="contrasena" translate>input.contrasena</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="contrasena" ng-model="loginPassword">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="login()" translate>input.autenticar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

            <div class="login col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" ng-controller="LoginController">
                <div class="panelLogin">
                      <label for="usuario" translate>input.usuario</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" ng-model="loginUsuario">
                      <label for="contrasena" translate>input.contrasena</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="contrasena" ng-model="loginPassword">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="login()" translate>input.autenticar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I've duplicated the form so it's both in and out of the grey wrapper. Then using bootstrap's show/hide classes I've hidden one for small screens "hidden-xs" and hidden the other for larger screens "hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg".